# The significance of the number 27 in M-Theory?

Tags: string-theory

I am curious about the properties of numbers, and patterns revolving around them. For example, 5 and 7 are interesting in the hyperbolic space because they form tessellations with interesting properties, as outlined in Margenstern's [Cellular Automata in Hyperbolic Spaces](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007/978-0-387-30440-3_53).

[image]

Likewise, for this question, I am curious about properties of the number [27](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/27_(number)), since it is the number of blocks in a cube like the Rubic's cube.

[image]

The main thing I'm curious about stems from the first point on the 27 Wiki page:

> Twenty-seven is a cube of 3: ${\displaystyle 3^{3}=3\times 3\times 3}$. There are exactly 27 straight lines on a smooth [cubic surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_surface), which give a basis of the fundamental representation of the $E_6$ Lie algebra.

I would ask about the meaning/significance of the $E_6$ Lie algebra, but Lie algebras are currently over my head at the moment, so I don't know how far I'd get in understanding the implications. But perhaps I can glean some insight into the sentence in the linked "cubic surface" Wiki page, which says:

> In physics, the 27 lines can be identified with the 27 possible charges of M-theory on a six-dimensional torus (6 momenta; 15 membranes; 6 fivebranes) and the group $E_6$ then naturally acts as the U-duality group. **This map between del Pezzo surfaces and M-theory on tori is known as mysterious duality.**

How can you explain what is done with the number 27 for more of a lay person? (I am a software engineer with a college degree in molecular biology, but don't have extensive advanced math background, though I know the terms and what to search to some degree). What is the "mysterious duality" they are talking about? I am not finding any information on that. And if at all possible, why do we care that there are 27 lines mapped to a 6-dimensional torus? Just looking for more insight into the meaning and structure of the pattern, which revolves around the number 27.

I know some Group Theory, I just am not intuitive yet with complex real numbers, which I think the Lie groups build upon.

Comment: $27$ is supposedly the target space dimension of [bosonic M-theoy](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bosonic+M-theory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String theory has a number of "dualities" in which different-looking string theories actually describe exactly the same thing. For example, one kind of string moving on one kind of space, turns out to be equivalent to a different kind of string moving on a different kind of space.

The so-called [**mysterious duality**](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0111068) is a specific correspondence which has not quite risen to the same level. So far, it is just pointing out that some properties of "11-dimensional M-theory with N of the dimensions compactified into small circles" correspond to properties of "what you get when you start with a particular 4d space (the complex projective plane) and replace N points with hollow spheres".

For example, you can consider certain kinds of transformations of the M-theory scenario (its "U-duality group"), and certain kinds of transformations of the punctured 4d space (certain "diffeomorphisms" of the space), and it turns out to be the same algebra of transformations, even though the underlying objects look quite different.

The Wikipedia article is talking about this correspondence, for the case N=6.

It has been suggested that the mysterious duality is a true duality - i.e. that the correspondence can be expanded into two alternative but equivalent descriptions of M-theory dynamics - if you consider ["(2,1) strings" on the punctured 4d space](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/string/archives/000265.html#c000386). ((2,1) is a kind of supersymmetry.) However, this remains unproven.